# screen buffer and dialog

Tags: run-dialog, tput, dialog

I was trying to use different screen buffer for my script using tput. Below is small script that I am running.

```
tput smcup
clear
dialog --yesno "Do you want to continue?" 0 0
rc=$?
clear
tput rmcup
if [ "${rc}" == "0" ]; then
  echo Yes
else
  echo No
fi
```

After the script is finished executing there is a blank part on the screen(as shown below in the image) which is equal to the rows occupied by the prompts before running the script.Ideally `tput` should have switched to second screen buffer and after executing it should have come back to the first screen buffer.
**The script switches to the second screen but after coming back it leaves a blank space which shouldn't be there .**

[image]

Comment: please add info like OS, version of `dialog`, terminal, what command you run with --keep-tite and what happens then... so people don't have to look through all the comments to get the full picture.

Answer (score 5):

It's an issue with the `dialog` implementation from http://invisible-island.net/dialog/dialog.html.

On startup, it does a `smcup` + `rmcup` by itself, I beleive because `ncurses` initialisation routine does the `smcup` and `dialog` wants to cancel that.
So if you do your `smcup` beforehand, it will have no effect, because the `rmcup` will cancel it.

A work around is to add the `--keep-tite` option which tells it not to do that, so `dialog` will do the `smcup` on start and `rmcup` on exit like other `ncurses` applications if the terminal supports it.

From your comments, you seem to have another problem: you're in a terminal that doesn't support an alternative screen, so whatever you do, you won't be able to use that alternate screen as it doesn't exist.

What you could do though is either use a different terminal that has an alternate screen like putty or the Unix ones from Cygwin on Cygwin's X Server. Or run an X terminal on the remote server to connect to and display on your X Server. Or run a terminal-based terminal emulator inside your terminal that supports an alternate screen like GNU `screen`.

Comment: output of `tput smcup | od -tc` is 

`0000000 033   [   ?   1   0   4   9   h
0000010`

and it doesn't switch to alternate screen and value of $TERM is `xterm`.Sorry I didn't understand about which implementation of `dialog` and --keep-tite didn't help.I use it like this `dialog --keep-tite --yesno "Do you want to continue?" 0 0`

Comment: uname -a gives
`Linux indlin534 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5 #1 SMP Sat May 7 20:18:50 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and cat /etc/issue gives `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)
`

Comment: What's the terminal? It doesn't look like an xterm. Does it work in xterm or other terminals? Are you using `screen` or `tmux` inside that terminal?

Comment: I am using mobaxterm software to connect to the server (ssh connection).

Comment: I have tried `putty` with no luck.I don't think you are right when you say that the problem is with the terminal.I have tested tput smcup and rmcup without dialog and it works fine,as per my understanding the problem here is with dialog implementation.If my terminal doesn't have an alternate screen,how am I able to use `vi` and other such commands that require a similar implementation ?

Comment: You said earlier that it "didn't switch to alternate screen", so I'm a bit confused now. Could you please edit your question with all the relevant information and what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Hi,I have made the edits,sorry for my poor explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is more complicated than suggested.  Start with the script:

```
tput smcup
clear
dialog --yesno "Do you want to continue?" 0 0
rc=$?
clear
tput rmcup
if [ "${rc}" == "0" ]; then
  echo Yes
else
  echo No
fi
```

There is only one alternate screen (and you cannot treat it like a stack).  The `tput smcup` (technically "start cursor-addressing mode") is often used with xterm and look-alikes to switch to the alternate screen.  There is actually more than one control sequence implemented in xterm for this purpose (see *[Why doesn't the screen clear when running vi?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite)*), and some are not recognized by the look-alikes.  In one of the comments, MobaXterm is said to be the actual terminal in this case.  That is based on (uses code from) PuTTY, which happens to handle the 1049 code in MobaXterm's terminfo.

So...

- the script switches to the alternate screen
- it clears that (again: xterm clears the alternate screen on the previous step)
- it runs dialog, *still* using the alternate screen.
- when dialog exits, it sends the `rmcup` sequence, switching back into the normal screen, whose content will be the same as before the script began
- then the screen is cleared.  Normally that causes the cursor to be moved to the upper left of the screen and then cleared, but (see below)
- finally, `tput rmcup` is used.  That asks the terminal emulator to switch back from the alternate screen.

Since the terminal is already in normal mode, that last line could be interpreted in one of (at least) two ways:

- it could be ignored
- some part of the operations performed in the switch from alternate to normal mode might be executed.

In this case, it seems that the latter: *part* is performed.  PuTTY (and in a quick check, xterm) restore the cursor position from the *first* use of `tput smcup`, because the prompt is in the middle of the screen (rather than at the top, where `clear` would leave it).  OP noticed a gap because there were several commands already done in that window before running the script—the cursor returns to the original position, but the commands are gone because of the `clear` before the `tput rmcup`.