# Output in terminal after quitting program

Tags: terminal, vim, less, rxvt, nano

I'm using Kubuntu with i3, and I've recently migrated from Manjaro because things. My terminal emulator is *urxvt* but, when I use programs such as *vim*, *less* or *nano* in the terminal remains the part of text displayed by the program before quitting. Do anyone know how to avoid this? I've also tried to put `export TERM='urxvt-256color'` into my `.bashrc` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Done, several times

Comment: The feature you're used to is called the alternate or secondary screen, and should be enabled by default.  Does `xrdb -query` show lines starting with either `XTerm*titeInhibit` or `urxvt*secondaryScreen` ?

Comment: Seems related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67883/117549