# How can I utilize the whole terminal, like htop or emacs do?

Tags: bash, terminal, gui, io

I want to write a program that can "draw" in the terminal the same way as htop or emacs. By that I mean "get rid of the prompt and make the output dependent on the current size of the terminal".

To make this a bit more clear:

I want to use the terminal this way:

[image]

in stead of this way:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do that, from lowlevel ones to more high level apis.

Check out `ncurses` for C and `dialog` for bash.

This is a very complete tutorial for ncurses: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/

Comment: What is the the functionality ncurses provides called? ("how do I google for this kind of thing?")

Comment: I added dialog for bash. It depends from what language you need the functionality for. I would google something like "ncurses for python" (which is PyNcurses)

Comment: @Bruno9779: I believe that townhall is asking “How do I do a Google search to find out that there is a thing called ‘ncurses’ if I don’t already know *that its name is ‘ncurses’*?”

Comment: @townhall: I did a Google search for “full-screen unix programming”, and the eighth result (on the first page) was [How to write full-screen Linux console app/script?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14221317/1672723) (on [SO]), the answers to which mention curses and ncurses.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/39302351/340790 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336635/5132 for some keywords.