# How to create a sub-window in a terminal?

Tags: shell-script, shell, terminal

I would like to print to a clean terminal, but not issue a `clear` or `reset` command such that the user will not lose data. After the printing is done, I would like to put the user in their old (root) window.

I see this done in programs like `htop`, `tmux`, `less` and the like. My understanding is that they create a new window on top of the root, use that, and return the user to the root window when done.

How can I emulate the same behaviour in a shell script? I (think I) cannot just pipe what I want to print to `less` as I need to capture the user's input.

Here's a template for what I need:

```bsh
begin-window # a top-layer window is created
echo data
read input
echo processed input
read _ # press enter to exit
end-window # user is returned to the original window
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally: [How do some tools (e.g. nano , less) manage to leave no content in terminals after exit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336609/108618)